# Can't see matplotlib plots in iPython notebook

Tags: macos, matplotlib, pandas, ipython, libpng

I'm trying to show pandas-generated plots in iPython notebooks (running with `pylab=inline`), but these have mysteriously stopped working—I'll do something like:

```
In [6]: pd.Series([0,2,4,3,8]).plot()
Out[6]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x10e69e110>
        <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x10eb40d90>
```

Note: there's no plots here, just the text.

I do, however, get these errors in the console where I'm running iPython:

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.5.18 but running with 1.6.10
```

How do I sort this out and get plots working again?

(I have libpng installed through homebrew, iPython v.1.1.0, matplotlib v.1.3.1)

---

UPDATE: Now I'm using iPython v.2.1.0.

I still get the libpng error, but in the notebook I now get

```
In [2]: pd.Series([0,2,4,3,8]).plot()
Out[2]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x112821110>
        /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: Could not create write struct
          FormatterWarning,
        <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x112788a50>
```

So... progress?

(I am also now using `%pylab inline` in the document, instead of using it as a command-line flag.)

Comment: Did you try `%pylab osx`?

Comment: I did. This pops the plots up in a separate window, which I suppose works, but really isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: You should probably try this on the latest version of IPython; try installing it using conda: http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda

Comment: Ok, now I'm using iPython 2.1 (I installed it through pip though). I get a different error (edited in above).

Answer (score 1):

```
 %pylab inline
```

work fine in my env

```
   %pylab inline
    pd.Series([0,2,4,3,8]).plot()
```

[image]

my Ipython(modules) version

```
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
certifi==14.05.14
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipython==2.3.0
matplotlib==1.4.2
mock==1.0.1
nose==1.3.4
numpy==1.9.1
pandas==0.15.1
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2014.9
pyzmq==14.4.1
six==1.8.0
tornado==4.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

pylab=inline is deprecated, and may have already been removed in the latest builds of IPython. You can still display plots inline with:

```
%pylab inline
```

Comment: Not in the current IPython build. It's been removed; see [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ipython.devel/12628).

Comment: I'm using iPython 1.1, which is not the current iPython build. pylab=inline has worked fine in this build in the past, and continues to work on my other computers.